# subseting a dataframe excluding top20 and lowest20

Tags: pandas

I am sampling a dataframe to get 3 new dataframes. The first 2 I use this code:

```
# Get Top 20 
top20 = df['column'].value_counts().keys()[:20]

# Get Lowest 20
low20 = df['column'].value_counts().keys()[-20:]
```

**What I want:**

How can I get the same daframe excluding the top 20 and low 20, I mean getting what's between top 20 and low 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
between = df['column'].value_counts().keys()[20:-20]
```